# How to use Perl HTML::TableExtract with rowspans and also spans within cells

Tags: perl, html-parsing, perl-module

I apologize for the length here, but I thought it made sense to include my small amount of progress in addition to a description of my problem!

I want to extract data from some html pages that have several tables on them. The critical table is, in the scheme used by `HTML::TableExtract`, at `depth=>0, count=>2`. The specific page I've used in the code example here is: http://www.myschool.edu.au/ResultsInNumbers/Index/61209/ConingsbyStateSchool/46701/2011 . It has an annoying Search-CAPTCHA at the start where you type, for example, "Coningsby". Ignoring the surrounding HTML, the table structure is essentially as shown in the block below.

```
<table class="results-in-numbers">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="year-column"></td>
      <th colspan="2" scope="col">Reading</th>
      <th colspan="2" scope="col">Writing</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="selected-school-row">
      <th scope="row" rowspan="3">Year 3</th>
      <td colspan="2">
        <span class="avg">449</span>
        <span class="err">404 - 494</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <span class="avg">395</span>
        <span class="err">359 - 431</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="color-row">
      <td><img src="" alt ="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" alt =""/></td>
      <td><img src="" alt ="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" alt =""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sim-all-row">
      <td>
        <span class="sim">SIM</span>
        <span class="sim-avg">411</span>
        <span class="err">402 - 420</span>
      </td>
      <td>
         <span class="all">ALL</span>
         <span class="sim-avg">416</span>
      </td>
      <td>
         <span class="sim">SIM</span>
        <span class="sim-avg">410</span>
        <span class="err">402 - 418</span>
      </td>
      <td>
         <span class="all">ALL</span>
         <span class="sim-avg">416</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have simplified the table in a couple of ways. First, there are actually five overall headings at the top, rather than just Reading and Writing, but the layout for each of the deleted replicates is exactly the same as those for Reading and Writing. Second, I have included only one the triplets of rows that correspond to "Year 3", as shown in the line  `<th scope="row" rowspan="3">Year 3</th>` . Possible importantly for my question is the fact that I do not know how many such rowspans there will be. On the example page there are 3 but sometimes there is only 1, with a maximum of 4.

I'd like to organize the data in the output so that is in comma-separated form with the relevant numbers for each year (as in "Year 3" on a single line), so I need to be able to detect the Year and then also capture the next two table rows, so that a single line of output, representing a single `rowspan="3"` block would read

```
3,449,404,494,395,359,431,411,402,420,416,410,402,418,416
```

with the 3 at the beginning representing "Year 3". I don't really know of a sensible way of dealing with the rowspan-ed block of three rows, so currently my code just produces the rows (including the unwanted blank row in the middle) as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use HTML::TableExtract;
use constant false => 0;
use constant true  => 1;
foreach $html_file (@ARGV) {
  print "$html_file \n";
  $te = HTML::TableExtract->new( gridmap => false, subtables => true );
  $te->parse_file($html_file);

  # I don't know how many rows there are in the table, so I don't
  # know how to count through them in triplets
  foreach my $r ( $te->table(0,2)->rows() ) {
      foreach my $col ( @$r ) {
        # remove unwanted white space that results from the multiple
        # spans within each <td> </td> block
        $col =~ s/[\h\v]+/ /g;
        # remove leading whitespace
        $col =~ s/^ *//;
        # remove trailing whitespace
        $col =~ s/ *$//;
        print $col, " ";
      }
      print "\n";
    }
  print "\n";
}

GotSchools/61/61998-61209-ConingsbyStateSchool-46701-2011-n
 Reading  Writing
Year 3 449 404 - 494  395 359 - 431

 SIM 411 402 - 420 ALL 416 SIM 410 402 - 418 ALL 416
```

I would appreciate advice on how to proceed. For example, should I use a regex to detect the Year at the beginning of a row, as well as to remove the words SIM and ALL? Also, there some pages where the entries that appear here as something like "402 - 418" actually have missing data with entries that might say " - ", which I would want to output as comma-delimiters without intervening content.

Any advice would be appreciated.